# Android SQLite update method not working properly. Using Content Provider

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am trying to update just one column in a row and for some reason it continues to tell me the column does not exist.

Content Provider

```
    @Override
public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = ucdb.getReadableDatabase();
    final int match = ContentDescriptor.URI_MATCHER.match(uri);
    int rowsUpdated = 0;
    switch(match){
    case ContentDescriptor.U.PATH_TOKEN:{
        rowsUpdated = db.update(ContentDescriptor.T1.NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    case ContentDescriptor.R.PATH_TOKEN:{
        rowsUpdated = db.update(ContentDescriptor.T2.NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    case ContentDescriptor.Q.PATH_TOKEN:{
        rowsUpdated = db.update(ContentDescriptor.T3.NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    case ContentDescriptor.S.PATH_TOKEN:{
        rowsUpdated = db.update(ContentDescriptor.T4.NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    case ContentDescriptor.E.PATH_TOKEN:{
        rowsUpdated = db.update(ContentDescriptor.T5.NAME, values, selection, selectionArgs);
    }
    }
    return rowsUpdated;
}
```

Update Query

```
ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
            val.put(ContentDescriptor.U.Cols.q, newQ);

            contentResolver.update(ContentDescriptor.U.CONTENT_URI, val,
                    ContentDescriptor.U.Cols.UID + "='" + uId + "'", null);
```

Comment: Did you recently add the column after you have already creates your database once?

Comment: Have you created this column / table recently? maybe you need to increase your database version.

Comment: yes one activity adds a row and another activity tries to modify the row by updating it

Comment: yes i recently added the column but i removed the app from the android device completely and reinstalled the app.

Comment: what does your creation of the table look like? it sounds like its something in your table creation if you uninstalled it and it is still happening

Comment: added creation of table code to original

Comment: Is it possible to execute database updates on a readable databases `ucdb.getReadableDatabase();` ?

Comment: probably because the column does not exist. it can be a typo, a lack of updating the table after you changed the schema, or another misunderstanding.

Comment: also, post stacktrace anyway

Comment: figured it out. the switcher needs to have breaks or return statements.

Answer (score 2):

the switcher needed breaks or return statements.

Comment: and every switch should have a default case... and T1 - T5 are great table names... really helps reading code with that kind of variable names...